# Optimize images to YSlow standards using PHP?

Tags: php, yslow, image-optimization

I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this question.

I want to losslessly optimize my images (mostly jpg) so that it satisfies YSlow's Image Optimization criteria. I haven't been able to determine what steps needed to be taken to do this.

I know of services like smush.it, but I don't want to rely on an API or service.

Basically what I am looking for is a list of steps to take to optimize an image according to YSlow's standards.

Just using GD and changing quality isn't enough, what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried generating progressive JPGs with [imageinterlace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageinterlace.php)? It makes smaller images slightly larger, but larger images much smaller. It was the last piece of the puzzle for my image optimization code.

#### Example code

```
<?php
$new_img = imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, $img_height);
imageinterlace($new_img, true); // Use progressive JPGs
$white = imagecolorallocate($new_img, 255, 255, 255);
imagefilledrectangle($new_img, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height, $white);
imagecopyresampled($new_img, $img, $x, $y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
header("content-type: image/jpg");
imagejpeg($new_img, NULL, 100);
imagedestroy($img);
imagedestroy($new_img);
die;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good rough equivalent of Smush.it capabilities are implemented in Mike Brittain's [Wesley](https://github.com/mikebrittain/Wesley) project. It's Perl rather than PHP, but you might be able to adapt it to your needs, or just shell out to it in the command line.

It implements the similar compression tools and steps as described in the [Smush.it FAQ](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/faq.html).